# Invalid input F

Tags: neo4j

I am running the following Cypher query in 4.1 and cannot see for the life of me why it is producing the error `Invalid input 'F': expected whitespace, comment, IF or ON` for the query `CREATE CONSTRAINT n_tester FOR (n:Test) REQUIRE n.Tester IS UNIQUE`.

Do Cypher queries have to be line separated? I added a couple of \n and it still errored - however that could well be php's `json_encode` doing something odd. What is wrong with the format of this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: [Neo4j 4.1 has reached End Of Life a while ago](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/neo4j-supported-versions/), please upgrade!

Generally speaking, you can find documentation for older versions [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/resources/docs-archive/).

For 4.1, the [constraint creation syntax](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.1/administration/constraints/) (adapted to your example) is as follows:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT n_tester ON (n:Test) ASSERT n.Tester IS UNIQUE
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax changes between versions. For 4.3:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT n_tester ON (n:Test) ASSERT n.Tester IS UNIQUE
```

For 4.1, the documentation doesn't even show constraints, so maybe that's not even available for that version.

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.3/constraints/syntax/

Comment: I personally couldn't even get the documentation for 4.1 as 4.3 is the latest.